# meaning of 'greasy dangers'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"....and I'm hungry, and I don't like to eat alone, and I'd be glad to have you face the **greasy dangers** of a meal at the Finn's with me.”

It's a part of 'Nightmare Town' by Dashiell Hammett (1924).

I don't think at that time people were too concerned about 'greasy food' as these days.

My opinion is the 'greasy dangers' in the cited sentence might have some other meaning, which I can't figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hammett is probably alluding to the uncertain quality of the food, not necessarily the questionable nutrition in greasy food. Likewise, small restaurants of dubious quality are called 'greasy spoons' because the dish-washing is not up to par, thus the quality of the victuals as well.

Comment: OED **greasy spoon**   *n. (also greasy restaurant) slang (orig. U.S.) a cheap and inferior eating-house.* First recorded use is actually a definition, in *Writer's Monthly* June **1925**. But they have **greasy** *Of food: Containing a disproportionate quantity of grease.* from 1592, so the basic concept of "[cheap] unappetising food" goes back a *long* way.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of [the story](https://books.google.ca/books?id=gu9VrKdfZvAC&pg=PT250&lpg=PT250&dq=%22greasy+dangers%22&source=bl&ots=r4q492NxPV&sig=vl2JV2dOURx5mEDwYXWJRycLqS0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BdbrVOjRNonuoAS4nIDgDg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22greasy%20dangers%22&f=false) the protagonist Steve Threefall is talking with Roy Kamp in order to get information about the town.

> "What do you do then?"
>
> The thin man shrugged his sharp shoulders.
>
> "That depends, he said, on who you are. If you're Dave Brackett" --he wiggled a finger at the red bank across the street-- "you gloat over your mortgages, or whatever it is a banker does; if you're Grant Fernie, and too big for a man without being quite big enough for a horse, you pin a badge on your bosom and throw rough-riding strangers into the can until they sober up; or if you're Larry Ormsby, and your old man owns the soda works, then you drive trick cars from across the pond" --nodding at the cream Vauxhall-- "and spend your days pursuing beautiful telegraph operators. But I take it that you're broke, and have just wired for money, and are waiting for the more or less doubtful results. Is that it?"
>
> "It is," Steve answered absent-mindedly

From here we see that Steve is presenting himself as not having money and perhaps looking for work. Given the context of this preceding paragraph, it appears that when Roy next says:

> "In that case it's lunchtime, and my name is Roy Kamp, and I'm hungry, and I don't like to eat alone, and I'd be glad to have you face the greasy dangers of a meal at the Finn's with me."

he's offering to take Steve to lunch, but doing so with a metaphor for offering someone a dangerous job. Taking someone along to face dangers is the kind of thing someone would do in the era that this was written in. In this case there's no real dangers (other than perhaps the quality of the food as IconDaemon noted), but it's a sort of joking way of inviting someone for lunch by posing it as a dangerous quest.

Answer (score 0):

Greasy dangers can also imply jokingly that your fingers and lips will get greasy, thus the danger.